# Why is the time complexity of the Bit Manipulation solution to Binary Addition O(M + N)?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arithmetic, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand why the time complexity of the Bit Manipulation solution (https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/solution/) to the Binary Addition problem is O(M + N), where M and N are the lengths of the input strings a and b, respectively.

From my understanding, the worst case scenario is that each column in the addition will result in a carry, and since there are max(N, M) columns, the time complexity should be O(max(N, M))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m,n>=0$, then $\max(m,n)<=m+n<=2\max(m,n)$.

So $O(\max (m,n))$ and $O(m+n)$ are the same; the two expressions are within a constant factor of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, when we compute binary addition of two binary strings $|A|=n,|B|=m$, we read $n+m$ bits. On the other hand the time complexity of computing the addition of two bits, are $\mathcal{O}(1)$, so we do $n+m$ additions that each of them needs $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time. As a result, the time complexity is
$$\mathcal{O}(n+m).$$

**Remember that, $A+B$ need at most $\max\{m,n\}+1$ bits space.**